# Merging mulit-valued dictionaries

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

Lets say I have two dictionaries with multiple values per key:

```
Dict1 = { key1 : [value1,value2] }
Dict2 = { key1 : [value3,value4], key2 : [value5,value6]}
```

I want to merge them into one dictionary like this:

```
mergedDict = { key 1 : [value1,value2,value3,value4], key 2 : [0,0,value5,value6] }
```

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-to-merge-two-python-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression

Comment: did you try any code?

Comment: What about repeated values? If there is value1 for key1 in Dict1 and value1 for key1 in Dict2 should the restulting dictionary have two occurences of value1 for key1, or just one?

Comment: @thavan yes i did, using something like mergedDict[key].append(value) but it would just append them not index them like I want

Comment: @Błotosmętek yes the resulting dict should have two occurences of value1 something like key1 : [value1,value2,value1,value3]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop over the union of the keys and use `dict.get` with the default value `[0, 0]`.

```
>>> dict1 = {'key1' : [1, 2]}
>>> dict2 = {'key1' : [3, 4], 'key2' : [5, 6]}
>>>
>>> {k:dict1.get(k, [0, 0]) + dict2.get(k, [0, 0]) for k in dict1.viewkeys() | dict2.viewkeys()}
{'key2': [0, 0, 5, 6], 'key1': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer man, I'll accept it just have to test it. One more request can we do this for more than two dictionaries? like four?

Comment: works like a charm buddy, can we do it for more than two dictionaries?

Comment: @MohsinKhalid yes, but then we need a clearer rule how the padding should work. Always two zeros when a key is missing from one dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it, and covers possibity of `Dict1` having keys that `Dict2` doesn't:

```
Dict1 = {'key1': ['value1', 'value2'], 'key3': ['value7', 'value8']}
Dict2 = { 'key1' : ['value3','value4'], 'key2' : ['value5', 'value6']}

mergedDict = {k: [0, 0] + v  if k not in Dict1 else Dict1[k] + v for k, v in Dict2.items()}
mergedDict.update({i: j + [0, 0] for i, j in Dict1.items() if i not in Dict2})
#{'key3': ['value7', 'value8', 0, 0], 'key2': [0, 0, 'value5', 'value6'], 'key1': ['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4']}
```

Comment: I provided solution for specific situation? What is wrong with that?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
dict1  = { 'key1' : ['value1','value2'] }
dict2 = { 'key1' : ['value3','value4'], 'key2' : ['value5','value6']}
dict3 = defaultdict(list)
for d1, d2 in dict1.items() + dict2.items():
    dict3[d1].extend(d2)
dict(dict3) #convert defaultdict to dict
```

Output:

```
{'key1': ['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4'],
 'key2': ['value5', 'value6']}
```

Comment: Does not produce expected result.

Comment: Does still not produce expected output. OP wants padding with zeros when a key is missing.